# Rails 3: RJS vs JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, rjs

I've recently started learning Ruby on Rails, based on RoR3 beta/RC. I had earlier been developing applications using other frameworks (like Django), where the JavaScript had been written completely on my own.

When developing application using RoR, I get confused by the two possible ways of implementing JavaScript: the "pure" one (writing JavaScript and putting it in the `<script>` tag) and writing RJS files.

Which of the approach should rather be used and when? If RJS, how do I implement particular actions like `onChange`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In rails you should use both approaches for different tasks. So do I. When I would like to execute ajax request, I use RJS because it simplifies the request and allows to write more powerful and flexible respond within .rjs file with a much less code. For example it is possible to use partials in it and to get access to ruby variables. When I would like to make a page more dynamic, I use plain javascript including it with `javascript_include_tag`.

**UPD.**
This approach works in rails 3 the same way. It's possible to use it with JQuery and HAML. UJS in Rails 3 even simplifies it. The only thing you should do is to use [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) if you prefer Jquery over Prototype and proper file naming like `create.js.haml`.
For example it possible to use [server-side validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952117/rails-3-ujs-dry-client-server-side-form-validation/4266542#4266542) in AJAX requests with this approach.

Answer (score 4):

In rails 3 the right way to do it is pure JS.
RJS is too strict and you have to use Prototype or hack in some way to use it with jQuery.
Rails 3 also promotes unobtrusive javascript. On AJAX requests you should return pure Javascript embed with ERB instead of using RJS.

Unfortunately since this change requires a lot of rework for older projects that used RJS some people will leave it be.

The RJS is actually depreciated in rails 3, you need a plugin to even work with it, so if you're starting now and you're lucky enough to start on rails 3 already, go the rails 3 way.

Here is a good example of the new UJS way:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

Good luck

Comment: This is the best answer. RJS should not be used anymore and the closest alternative is to render a `.js.erb` file.  If the client makes an AJAX request (type 'script' if using jQuery) then the server action would, for example, `render partial: '/whatever/partial'`. The partial file would be `PROJECT_ROOT/app/views/whatever/_partial.js.erb`.